Demailly’s proof of the existence of good covers
In this MathOverflow thread, an argument for proving the existence of good covers of smooth manifolds that doesn’t use Riemannian geometry or an embedding to Euclidean space is sketched by BS. I think it is the same argument as in Lemma IV-6.9 of Complex Analytic and Differential Geometry by Demailly.
I am confused about something in this argument. It seems to me that in the constructed cover finite intersections may not be connected. For example, we can cover a circle by two connected open intervals with the transition map in either direction given by two translations. What ensures that in Demailly’s procedure we don’t just end up with another cover by two slightly smaller intervals? If we know that the finite intersections are connected, then I see why the cover would be a good cover. Am I missing something? I think I know what the mistake is but I want to make sure that I am not being stupid.
In fact, am I not correct that in this argument we didn’t use the Hausdorff property for example? The result (existence of good covers) is false for the gluing of two real lines via the identity map along their non-zero loci.
Is there really an argument along these lines?

I think the problem might be a bit worse than just not having connected intersections. For example if $X = \mathbb{S}^2$ and you take the north and south hemispheres with a bit of "excess" (so that it is no longer geodesically convex), then the intersection is connected but not contractible.

However, if $X$ is Hausdorff and paracompact, then it is fully normal. So, I think we can barycentrically refine the atlas with open sets such that each set is convex in every chart fully containing it.

Regarding the first comment: I think you might be underestimating the argument. It does achieve something. Namely that each finite intersection is diffeomorphic to a finite disjoint union of convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$. For example if you start with $S^2$ and its cover by thickened hemispheres with stereographic charts, it will not return a slightly shrunk version of such a cover. The function 1/(x^2+y^2) is nowhere convex in the complement of the origin in the plane. I don’t understand how convexity is achieved in your second comment. Are you starting with a triangulation (not allowed)?

I misunderstood what you really meant by "If we know that the finite intersections are connected, then I see why the cover would be a good cover." I was giving an (unnecessary, in retrospect) example of why that alone wouldn't be sufficient.

As for the argument, strict convexity requires $B(a, \epsilon) \cap \Omega'_k$ to be convex (and hence connected) in the chart for $\Omega_j$, which your example for $\mathbb{S}^1$ doesn't seem to satisfy. For example, if you use stereographic charts you get the function $1/x^2$ defined on $\mathbb{R}-{0}$ which is not strictly convex. I think you can take a star-refinement and by the same argument as Demailly take sufficiently small balls that are convex in each coordinate chart containing it. Then the union of finitely many sets which intersect will be contained in a single chart.

I gave a similar argument without using Riemannian geometry in my lecture notes: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_WxFupPeAeHyLAp6bzaJur2ReHuNZemo/view?usp=drive_link

@user527492 Notice that I am not using stereographic coordinates. I see the circle as real line modulo integers.

@BenMcKay the link is telling me that I don’t have permission

@UmutVarolgunes in that case, I still think your $\epsilon$ is too large, violating the requirement that the function is strictly convex (it needs a convex domain), so your example does not follow the construction. From the phrasing of the argument I don't think it's immediately clear that you can choose such $\epsilon$ but the proposed alternative should work.

Here is another link to my lecture notes. (The argument is the same as Demailly and Weil): https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E6aitHTpaYDXZSxBE12qF8EmoqkbsZnw/view?usp=sharing

Your example does not follow the construction since you have not taken $\epsilon$ small enough so that the functions $|\tau_{jk}(x)-\tau_{jk}(a)|^2$ are all strictly convex on $B(a, \epsilon) \cap \Omega_k'$. This is because the intersection of your ball with $\Omega_k'$ is not connected and strict convexity requires that you have a convex domain in $\Omega_j$. Without this, you only have that the functions are convex on each convex connected component. The question then is if it is possible to choose $\epsilon$ such that $B(a, \epsilon) \cap \Omega_k'$ is always convex.  This doesn't seem to be addressed in the proof, and any proof of this fact must make crucial use of the Hausdorff axiom (consider what happens if $a$ is one of the two origins on the line with two origins). However, there is a still a proof along these lines that I will present.
First, we demonstrate the existence of open sets diffeomorphic to a convex set for a finite collection of charts containing it, roughly following the ideas given by BS. and Vitali Kapovitch.

Lemma. Let $X$ be a $\mathrm{C}^2$-manifold and $x \in X$ . If $\{(W, \varphi_i)\}_{i=0}^{k}$ are a finite collection of charts from some common open set $W$ containing $x$, then there exists an open set $B \subseteq W$ containing $x$ such that $\varphi_i(B)$ is convex for each $i \in \{0, \ldots, k\}$.

Proof. Let $\tau_{ij} = \varphi_{i} \circ \varphi_{j}^{-1} \colon \varphi_j(W) \to \varphi_i(W)$ be the $\mathrm{C}^2$ transition maps and define $s_0 \colon W \to \mathbb{R}$ by $s_0(y) = |\varphi_0(y) - \varphi_0(x)|^2$. By construction, $\mathrm{Hess}(s_0 \circ \varphi_0^{-1})$ is positive-definite at $\varphi_0(x)$. However, since the Hessian is diffeomorphism invariant at critical points, we have that $\mathrm{Hess}(s_0 \circ \varphi_0^{-1} \circ \tau_{0i}) = \mathrm{Hess}(s_0 \circ \varphi_i^{-1})$ is also positive-definite at $\tau_{i0}(x)$ for each $i \in \{0, \ldots, k\}$. For convenience, let $t_i = s_0 \circ \varphi_i^{-1}$. Since positive-definiteness of the Hessian at a point implies local strict convexity, for each $i \in \{0, \ldots, k\}$ there exists some $\epsilon_i > 0$ such that $t_i$ is strictly convex on $\{ t_i < \epsilon_i\}$. Take $\epsilon = \min(\epsilon_0, \ldots, \epsilon_k)$ and define $B_i = \varphi_i^{-1}(\{t_i < \epsilon\})$. Since $t_i$ is strictly convex and $\epsilon \leq \epsilon_i$, we have that $\varphi_i(B_i) = \{t_i < \epsilon\}$ is convex. Furthermore,
$$
B_i = \varphi_i^{-1}(\{t_i < \epsilon\}) = (t_i \circ \varphi_i)^{-1}\big([0 ,\epsilon)\big) = s_0^{-1} \big([0 ,\epsilon)\big),
$$
so all the $B_i$ are equal and contain $x$, since $s_0(x) = 0$.

Now we may prove the existence of good covers.
Let $X$ be a paracompact $\mathrm{C}^2$-manifold and let $\{(U_\alpha, \varphi_\alpha)\}_{\alpha \in A}$ be a locally finite atlas. Since $X$ is fully normal, there exists a barycentric refinement $\mathscr{V} = \{V_\beta\}_{\beta \in B}$ of the atlas. For each $x \in X$, there exists some $\beta(x) \in B$ such that $x \in V_{\beta(x)}$. By local-finiteness, there exists an open set $W_x$ such that $x \in W_x \subseteq V_{\beta(x)}$ and $W_x \cap U_\alpha \neq \varnothing$ only for $\alpha$ belonging to some finite subset $A_x \subseteq A$. Let $A'_x$ be the set of all $\alpha \in A_x$ such that $W_x \subseteq U_\alpha$. Then by the Lemma, there exists an open set $B_x \subseteq W_x$ containing $x$ such that for all $\alpha \in A'_x$, the image $\varphi_\alpha(B_x)$ is convex. So, consider the open cover $\mathscr{B} = \{B_x\}_{x \in X}$. We will show that it is good.
Suppose that $B_{x_0} \cap \cdots \cap B_{x_k} \neq \varnothing$. Then there exists some $y \in B_{x_0} \cap \cdots \cap B_{x_k} \subseteq V_{\beta(x_0)} \cap \cdots \cap V_{\beta(x_k)}$. Hence $V_{\beta(x_i)} \subseteq \mathrm{star}(y, \mathscr{V})$ for each $i \in \{0, \ldots, k\}$, and since $\mathscr{V}$ is a barycentric refinement, there exists some $\alpha \in A$ such that $\mathrm{star}(y, \mathscr{V}) \subseteq U_\alpha$. In particular, $V_{\beta(x_i)} \subseteq U_\alpha$ for each $i \in \{0,\ldots,k\}$. It follows that $\alpha \in A'_{x_0} \cap \cdots \cap A'_{x_k}$ by definition, so $\varphi_\alpha(B_{x_i})$ is a convex subset of $\varphi_\alpha(U_\alpha)$ for each $i \in \{0,\ldots,k\}$. Hence the image of the intersection $\varphi_\alpha(B_{x_0} \cap \cdots \cap B_{x_k})$ is convex and hence contractible.

I will read the proof in detail, thank you for writing it. But, why do you say that my example does not follow the construction. Why do you think I have to take $\epsilon$ small? Translations keep strictly convex  functions strictly convex. Convexity of a function does not include any assumptions about the convexity of its domain as far as I know.

The proof looks good to me for now. I will read it again today and if it still looks ok, I will accept it.

The definition of a convex function requires the domain to be convex. Otherwise, you cannot proceed in the latter half of Demailly's argument, since level sets would not be guaranteed to be convex sets.
